# Loading JSON via Angular Service fails in IE9

Tags: json, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

In my view I am loading some data via AngularJS Service. This works great with modern browsers, but fails terribly with Internet Explorer 9 and below. When I'm calling the Controller that returns (normally) JSON like

```
[{"id":2,"title":"Product","slug":"product","short_description"...}]
```

is opening an "Save"-dialog in IE9. Thus, the call in the service returns the markup of the current HTML-site. Which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        ...
```

The method call in the controller looks like this:

```
Product.get()
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    })
    .error(function(msg) {
        $log.error(msg);
    });
```

The `Product.get()`-Service is basically just `$http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products')`

UPDATE: `this.JSON` returns false... could you suggest a workaround, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IE9 is much more picky when parsing json than modern browsers.

It might be that you need to escape the HTML while serializing it on the server.

In C# as an example this can be achieved by Newtonsoft's
StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm)

Hope this helps!